# Netbeans Unexpected token SEMI found whit the boostrap.min.css file

Tags: css, parsing, netbeans, ide

I have a node js project, and I using Netbeans IDE for edit the code.

When I add the bootstrap.min.css file  to the sources tree, I have many error messages in this file and the IDE cant read the file for code autocompletition.

I use the official bootstrap.min.css file version 4.0.0 and the downloaded file to this url: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Any sugestion for this problem?

[image]

Comment: The problem is due to bootstrap use custom variables and Nebtbeans do no support. I refer a bug reported in the official comunity of netbeans: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262769

Comment: You can ignore this error, I think it will work fine. Actually Netbeans is not perfectly compatible with bootstrap 4. Or try to update all the plugins of Netbeans